# What do the following sentences mean?

Tags: meaning, difference

1. I could be sent back home, but he gave me another chance.
2. I could have been sent back home, but he gave me another chance.
3. I could have been sent/could be sent back home, but he had given me another chance.

When to use them,  What do they mean? What are the differences?

Comment: #1 is completely invalid, because *I could be sent back home* is a Present Tense assertion, so it's not valid to contrast it with Past Tense *he **gave** me [something]*. #2 is fine and would usually be what you want. #3 is valid, but *only* if the "narrative reference time" is already in the past ***and*** him giving you another chance was something that happened ***before*** the time in the past that you're mainly talking / writing about.

Comment: In some contexts, the speaker might wish to convey that even though it didn't (yet) happen, *he could still be sent home* at time of speaking. In that case, I'd say #1 is still "invalid", but at least *some* native speakers might choose to deliberately mix up the verb tenses in order to make that point (that the threat of being sent home is still "current").

Comment: Sir, then, "Oh.. finally he gave me another chance, but I think I could be sent back home" would it be correct?

Comment: I *think* you understand the point I was making in my second comment (why would a native speaker try to combine Present and Past tense verbs as in your example #1?). But your example in the comment immediately above *this* one doesn't really illustrate the point (your "Oh, finally..." is irrelevant). But a native speaker might combine Past Tense (what someone ***did***) with Present Tense (what the speaker ***thinks*** his current circumstances are) by saying something like *He didn't expel me this morning, but **I still think I could be expelled** (by him or someone else) in the near future*.